# Access Composite class fields from Component class

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I have two classes 'Employee' (composite class) and 'Salary' (component class).

I want to get value of a variable named 'self.abc' (defined in Employee class) in 'Salary' class. How can I get that?

Currently I'm getting an error `AttributeError: 'Salary' object has no attribute 'abc'`. Please help.

**I don't wanna use inheritance approach here.**

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, pay, bonus):
        self.abc = 100
        self.pay = pay
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.obj_salary = Salary(self.pay)
        self.annual_salary()
 
    def annual_salary(self):
        print("Total: " + str(self.obj_salary.get_total() + self.bonus))


class Salary:
    def __init__(self, pay):
        self.pay = pay
 
    def get_total(self):
        print(self.abc) # want to get 'abc' value here from 'Employee' class
        return (self.pay*12)
 
 
obj_emp = Employee(600, 500)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution would simply be to pass the `Employee` object as an argument to the `Salary` constructor, like so:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, pay, bonus):
        self.abc = 100
        self.pay = pay
        self.bonus = bonus
        self.obj_salary = Salary(self)
        self.annual_salary()
 
    def annual_salary(self):
        print("Total: " + str(self.obj_salary.get_total() + self.bonus))


class Salary:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.pay = parent.pay
        self.parent = parent
 
    def get_total(self):
        print(self.parent.abc)
        return (self.pay*12)
 
 
obj_emp = Employee(600, 500)
```

Note that in the above code, `obj_emp.obj_salary.pay` will not be updated if `obj_emp.pay` is, meaning in the following code:

```
obj_emp = Employee(600, 500)
obj_emp.pay = 700
print(obj_emp.obj_salary.pay)
```

The last `print` statement will print 600, not 700.

If you ever do need to reference `pay` dynamically within `Salary`, you can always use `self.parent.pay` rather than `self.pay`; this will refer to the connected `Employee` object's `pay` value.

Comment: Why have you replaced the statement ```self.pay = pay``` in **Salary** class with ```self.pay = parent.pay```? Please explain.

Comment: @deepanshu it results in the same value for `self.pay`, just removes the need to pass it as a parameter because you're setting it to the Employee object's `self.pay` anyway. It just simplifies things; you can change it back to using `pay` as a parameter if necessary.

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to explicitly tell `Salary` thay information when you initialize it, or after. You could pass the `abc` value to the initializer along with `pay`:

```
class Salary:
    def __init__(self, pay, abc):
        self.employee_abc = abc
```

and then in `Employee.__init__`:

```
self.obj_salary = Salary(self.pay, self.abc)
```

or give `Salary` the instance of `Employee` that it's a member of and access `abc` through that:

```
self.obj_salary = Salary(self.pay, self)
```

The benefit of the first way is you're only telling `Salary` enough information for it to be able to do its job, which is good. You don't want `Salary` depending heavily on the design of `Employee`.

The benefit of the second way is if you change `self.abc` in the `Employee` object, it will automatically be reflected in the `Salary` as well (although, this could also be seen as a down-side).